# Why is the colour of the texts written by inks appearing Yellowish and Purplish and not the printed one?

Tags: optics, visible-light

I was revising some of the concepts from my old copies and I noticed something really weird (might not be weird for others). The texts with black pen when seen from behind the page had some yellowish and somewhat purplish  appearance  (as shown in figure)

**1** : [image]

[image]

**2** :[image]

[image]

**3** : [image]

[image]

(the texts might not be clearly visible in the last one) . Also the third one was observed on the pages of a book while the first two were on the pages of a copy.

**1** : So I just want to know **how** is this happening ?

**Edit** : After reading @niels nielsen's answer , my above doubt was cleared but I have still  a question which he didn't referred in his answer.

**2** : Why doesn't this same phenomenon happens with the texts printed on the paper of books ?

So help me with them .

Comment: Help me with tags. I couldn't find a proper one.

Comment: You should have asked it on Chemistry StackExchange, as it is clearly chemical-reaction related question.

Comment: @HiterDean  I thought it as an optical phenomenon and that's why I asked it on this site.

Comment: In my opinion the ink undergone some chemical changes. When you put iron in contact with moisture it experiences corrosion ( a chemical reaction) hence changing its colour and other properties. Similarly In this case the ink undergone a chemical reaction hence changing its colour.

Comment: read this https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chromism and this https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ink

Answer (score 7):

You are demonstrating *paper chromatography* here, in which the diffusion speed of a chemical in wet paper depends on its chemical characteristics, including its molecular weight, and can be used to separate mixtures of different chemicals.

Black ink is actually a mixture of different dyes that are chosen to tint the basic black so it pleases the eye. Yellow is a common addition. Here, the yellow dye is penetrating the paper faster than any of the other color components, and once the water evaporates from the ink vehicle, the colors are locked in place.

This effect does NOT occur in printed books because the colorants used in book-printing inks are *pigments* ground into fine particles and the ink vehicles are not water-based. In addition, it is common for high-speed printing presses to use inks that cure to hardness under ultraviolet light, which chemical reaction renders them almost completely insoluble.

Anyway, you can greatly magnify this effect by putting a piece of paper in a shallow dish, wetting it with water, pouring off the excess, and then touching the pen tip to the center of the piece of wet paper. Ink will be drawn into the paper and then the different dye components in it will segregate themselves out in concentric rings of color.

Comment: what about the purplish appearance and the one with a blue pen ?

Comment: Same comments. Try the experiment I suggest!

Comment: can you help me with the second question ?

Comment: also why is the yellow colour penetrating faster and why not any other ?

Comment: without knowing anything at all about the specific yellow dye used here, it is impossible to say.

Comment: regarding your other comment, I have edited my answer to include it.

Comment: do you mean that printers use highly volatile compounds in place of water and the pigments can't penetrate the paper because of the vehicle evaporating quickly ?

Comment: what information would be needed  to find the penetration  rate of the pigments other than their molecular weight ?

Comment: their particle size, and the viscosity of the (oil-based) ink itself.

Comment: dye-based home printer ink is mostly water and "dries" not by evaporation but by adsorption into the paper, which is made to be porous. Evaporation comes later. pigment-based book-printing ink dries by evaporation under heated conditions and does not penetrate the paper; it adheres to its surface.